# How to resolve systemd (code=exited, status=227/NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES)?

Tags: debian, systemd, redis

I am trying to install the GitLab community package on a Debian Stretch system, but one of its dependencies, `redis-server`, fails to install when starting the service using systemd.

### Complete log:

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure redis-server
Setting up redis-server (3:3.2.5-4) ...
Job for redis-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status redis-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript redis-server, action "start" failed.
● redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-12-15 15:00:17 UTC; 31ms ago
 Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
       man:redis-server(1)
  Process: 8764 ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf (code=exited, status=227/NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES)
  Process: 8761 ExecStartPre=/bin/run-parts --verbose /etc/redis/redis-server.pre-up.d (code=exited, status=227/NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES)
 Main PID: 24283 (code=exited, status=227/NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES)

Dec 15 15:00:17 Serverdatorn-Debian systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Unit entered failed state.
Dec 15 15:00:17 Serverdatorn-Debian systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
dpkg: error processing package redis-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 redis-server
```

Starting redis-server by running the executable manually works perfectly:

```
$ sudo /usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
$ sudo tail /var/log/redis/redis-server.log
...
* The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
```

If there is any other information you want me to provide, please tell me.

### EDIT:

I tried setting `NoNewPrivileges` to both `yes` and `no` in the `redis.service` file, reloading and starting it again, but no luck, same error. I did find that running `journalctl -xe` showed another message that might be helpful:

```
redis-server.service: Failed at step NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES spawning /usr/bin/redis-server: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess you are running into this result of the `systemd` [NoNewPrivileges=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#NoNewPrivileges=) directive. Assuming that the `redis-server` package generally works Ubuntu 16.04 systems, this suggests that your system may custom global settings for `NoNewPrivileges=` or a related directive that's causing Redis to fail to start.

Read the docs linked about about `NoNewPrivileges=` and the related directives, then search in your `/etc/systemd/` directory to see if any of those values have been customized on your system. If not, confirm that the  `redis` package you are installing is indeed supported on the operating system version you are installing it on.

Comment: At first when I tried this, it didn't work. I tried it just now, and all of sudden, it works. I can now install the package and everything.

Answer (score 1):

This has been raised as a Debian bug, back in December 2017, but the bug was closed without a service fix.
If you have the details that Chris Lamb requested, please supply them.

A similar problem was reported for Debian's MariaDB 10.1 package back in July 2017, which was closed without fix when the package was removed from Debian.

A [local fix](http://jdebp.uk./FGA/fix-terminology.html) is to change the service's settings to be

```
NoNewPrivileges=no
PrivateDevices=no
```

Do not edit `/etc/systemd/system/redis.service` or `/usr/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service` directly.
The latter is not supposed to be hand-edited by local administrators at all, and the former isn't the actual service unit file that comes with the Debian package.

Instead use `systemctl edit redis.service` to create a *unit drop-in file* and put the settings there.
This also does a `daemon-reload` implicitly, which one would have to do by hand if one were modifying unit files by hand.

For those trying to find this in the source package:
The packaged `redis.service` and `redis@.service` files are generated by a Debian program called [`generate-systemd-service-files`](https://sources.debian.org/src/redis/5:5.0.3-4+deb10u2/debian/bin/generate-systemd-service-files/).

This is one of several problems that people have had with use of systemd's restriction mechanisms in the service units that are generated and packaged by the Debian people.
Others are that its `ProtectHome=yes` setting stops a symbolically linked `/home` from working, in a launchpad bug, and that its `ReadOnlyDirectories=/` setting yields a 226/NAMESPACE error code, in a StackOverflow Q&A.
The *local* fix takes the same form for all, a drop-in unit file with a setting override.

## Further reading

- Mauro Ziliani (2017-12-19).  *[redis-server exit with code 227/NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=884764)*.  Debian bug #884764.
- Andrew France (2016-11-01).  *[redis-server fails to start after 16.04 to 16.10 upgrade](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/redis/+bug/1638410)*.  Launchpad bug #1638410.
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48496530/340790
- ozzloy palindromemordnilap (2017-07-03).  *[mariadb install fails with NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES (systemd)](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=867137)*.  Debian bug #867137.
- [systemctl - service exit codes and status information explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/458648/5132)

Answer (score 0):

You can set PrivateDevices=false in the systemd service file to get it working.

Comment: You are right, however, need to do `systemctl daemon-reload` to make it effective.

Answer (score 0):

I do a resume:

You need to add to the `/etc/systemd/system/redis.service` file the follow lines:

```
NoNewPrivileges=no

PrivateDevices=no
```

After uncounted times I found that corrections works.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was running old Linux kernel from previous Debian version and couple of services failed to start with "(code=exited, status=227/NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES)" error. For example:

```
ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-logind (code=exited, status=227/NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES)
```

Installing current distribution kernel with `sudo apt-get install linux-image-amd64 && reboot` fixed my problem.