# redis-server doesn't start as a service on Debian 10 because of status=227/NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES

Tags: debian, systemd, vps, redis

I have a Debian 10, on a Digital Ocean droplet, I'm trying to install and run Redis as a service, which won't start because and error related to NoNewPriviliges.

I've reviewed the similar question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330637/how-to-resolve-systemd-code-exited-status-227-no-new-privileges), but the attempts yields no change.

I'm having a really hard time debugging this. I tried [reading up on this](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#NoNewPrivileges=), but I don't see what the problem could be.

The output from `systemctl status redis-server.service` is giving me the following output:

```
● redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-08-09 08:41:06 UTC; 53s ago
     Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
           man:redis-server(1)
  Process: 9553 ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf (code=exited, status=227/NO_NEW_PRIVILEGES)
```

The `/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service` file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Advanced key-value store
After=network.target
Documentation=http://redis.io/documentation, man:redis-server(1)

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID
PIDFile=/run/redis/redis-server.pid
TimeoutStopSec=0
Restart=always
User=redis
Group=redis
RuntimeDirectory=redis
RuntimeDirectoryMode=2755

UMask=007
PrivateTmp=yes
LimitNOFILE=65535
PrivateDevices=yes
ProtectHome=yes
ReadOnlyDirectories=/
ReadWriteDirectories=-/var/lib/redis
ReadWriteDirectories=-/var/log/redis
ReadWriteDirectories=-/var/run/redis

NoNewPrivileges=true
CapabilityBoundingSet=CAP_SETGID CAP_SETUID CAP_SYS_RESOURCE
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=true
ProtectKernelModules=true
ProtectKernelTunables=true
ProtectControlGroups=true
RestrictRealtime=true
RestrictNamespaces=true
RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_INET AF_INET6 AF_UNIX

# redis-server can write to its own config file when in cluster mode so we
# permit writing there by default. If you are not using this feature, it is
# recommended that you replace the following lines with "ProtectSystem=full".
ProtectSystem=true
ReadWriteDirectories=-/etc/redis

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=redis.service
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111708/discussion-on-question-by-repox-redis-server-doesnt-start-as-a-service-on-debia).

Comment: Don't know if the question is relevant more, though. Migrated to Ubuntu and everything just worked.

Comment: Glad you found a solution that works for you! I just closed this since you won't be needing it any more.